# What is the difference in declaring a Binding property in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding

What is the difference declaring a binding property in SwiftUI i.e

```swift
@Binding var foo: String
```

versus

```swift
var foo: Binding<String>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you do `@Binding var foo: String`, then you sort of simultaneously declare three things:

- `foo`, which is a `String`,
- `_foo`, which is a `Binding<String>` (this is private)
- `$foo`, which is a `Binding<String>`

The relationship between `foo`, `_foo` and `$foo` is:

```
// this is basically how property wrappers are implemented under the hood
private var _foo: Binding<String>
var foo: String {
    get { _foo.wrappedValue }
    set { _foo.wrappedValue = newValue } 
}
var $foo: Binding<String> {
    _foo.projectedValue
}
```

See also [the SE proposal for more details](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#proposed-solution).

---

If you do `var foo: Binding<String>`, you just get `foo`, which is a `Binding<String>`. There's no such thing as `$foo` and `_foo`.

Since `Binding<String>` is marked with `@dynamicMemberLookup`, you are still able to use `String`'s members on this `foo`, so it may look like `foo` is a `String` on first sight, but it is still of type `Binding<String>` as far as the type system is concerned. For example, you cannot use it in places where a `String` normally would work:

```
Text(foo) // error
```

Comment: excellent answer. I learned something too.